# How can I get the unique ID of a user who is currently signed in to my web app

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to link a document to each signed in user which will store their data to firestore,to do this i'm planning to use the auto generated userid which will be unique to each user to differentiate the documents.
I have already designed a home page where the user can input the data,im having trouble handling the user id generation.here is the code snippet:

```
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-auth.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {

        apiKey: "**",
        authDomain: "**",
        projectId: "**",
        storageBucket: "**",
        messagingSenderId: "**",
        appId: "**",
        measurementId: "**"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    const auth = getAuth();

    const user = auth.currentUser;
        const userId = user.uid;
        // Step 3: Store user-specific data in Firestore
        const firestore = firestore();
        // Create a reference to the users collection and the document for the current user
        const usersCollection = firestore.collection("users");
        const userDocument = usersCollection.doc(userId);

        function submitForm() {
            const movieSelect = document.getElementById("movieSelect");
            const seatCount = document.getElementById("seatCount").value;
            const showTime = document.getElementById("showTime").value;

            // Get the selected movie name from the select field
            const movieName = movieSelect.options[movieSelect.selectedIndex].text;

            // Define the data to store for each user
            const userData = {
                ticketCount: parseInt(seatCount),
                showTiming: showTime,
                movieName: movieName
            };

            // Set the user-specific data in the Firestore document
            userDocument.set(userData)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("User data stored successfully!");
                    window.location.href = 'selectseats.html';
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error storing user data: ", error);
                });
        }
</script>
```

I tried deploying the project to firebase,it is hosting but when i press the select seats button there are errors in the console and the uid is not being retrieved

Comment: "How can I get the uniquely generated user of a user" what?

Comment: "there are errors in the console" Please copy/paste those error (and their stack trace) into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the user isn't signed in yet when you inspect `auth.currentUser` in your current code. To fix that, you'll typically want to use an auth state listener as shown in the first code sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-namespaced-api):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

In your code that could be something like this:

```
let userId;
let userDocument;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    userId = user.uid;
    userDocument = usersCollection.doc(userId);
  } else {
    userId = null;
  }
});
```

And then of course when you change the `userId` variable, you'll want to make  sure that also run all the code that depends on that variable.

---

A simpler approach for this specific case is to only get the current user and determine their document reference inside the `submitForm` function:

```
function submitForm() {
    if (!auth.currentUser) throw new Error("Needs current user");
    let userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
    let userDocument = firebase.firestore().collection("users").document(userId);

    ...

    // Set the user-specific data in the Firestore document
    userDocument.set(userData)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("User data stored successfully!");
            window.location.href = 'selectseats.html';
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error storing user data: ", error);
        });
}
```